# Disable Spring Cloud Sleuth when running Integration Tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stackdriver, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-gcp

When using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace:1.0.0.RELEASE` and running my integration tests locally I get this error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'stackdriverSender' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/trace/StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [zipkin2.reporter.Sender]: Factory method
>   'stackdriverSender' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not
>   available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine.
>   Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
>   must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

This is totally understandable since this environment variable is not present locally and I don't want to use Sleuth/Stackdriver tracing when running the tests. I've looked in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle) but I can only seem to find information on how to disable Sleuth for specific integration points such as RxJava, RestTemplate etc. But how can I disable Sleuth entirely?

I've tried setting `spring.sleuth.enabled=false` but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer by looking at the [source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/trace/StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration.java) for the [StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/trace/StackdriverTraceAutoConfiguration.html) class. The way to solve it if using GCP is to set `spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false`. This disables tracing for all integration points.

Answer (score 3):

**HowTo: Disable all tests for a Webflux Sleuth implementation with Zipkin**

If, you have these dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin'
```

Then, fully disable Sleuth/Zipkin for your integration tests by adding an application.yml to your test/resources folder with:

```
spring:
  sleuth: # All sleuth features disabled for integration tests
    enabled: false
    reactor:
      enabled: false
    web:
      enabled: false
    async:
      enabled: false
      client:
        template:
          enabled: false
  zipkin: # All zipkin features disabled for integration tests
    enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tracing, logging and set a fake project id as follow:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=fake-project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false
```